# Texture painting in game engine

Tags: game-engine, uv, texture-painting

When I paint a texture, I can see the results when I press p.

[image]

But when I include the scene in my game using `logic.getBlendFileList`, I just see the 1st texture :

[image]

Looks like something is not properly packed... When I try to uncheck "automatically pack" and "pack all files" again, I get a "some images modified, changes will be lost, continue?" and sure enough, if I continue, the rock and sand brushes/textures are lost.

How can I make sure the new painted material gets packed? Alternatively, is there a way to make a new image out of the 3, to UV map on to the mesh once everything is painted, ensuring its consistency (at the cost of terrain editability) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found out (in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWjroD6K47Y)) in the UV image editor displaying your painted texture, **menu image/Save as image** (`F3`). That's it, save the file, your multi-texture is packed.

NB: If you paint the image again, repeat the steps but end with **image/Reload image** (`Alt-s`)